# How can I add meta-data to recorded flv-files in red5?

Tags: java, video, metadata, flv, red5

I wonder how to you can add meta-data to flv-files you recorded by red5...

mine just have something like this:

```
0.000 | FLV::Event tag
      | event          : onMetaData
      | audiocodecid   : -1
      | canSeekToEnd   : true
      | videocodecid   : -1
      | duration       : 0
```

Comment: What do you want to add?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [flvtool2](http://rubyforge.org/projects/flvtool2/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Manitu Group's [FLV Meta Data Injector](http://www.buraks.com/flvmdi/) is what you want?

> FLV MetaData Injector (FLVMDI) is a
>   Win32 console (command line)
>   application that can add 'onMetaData'
>   AMF data to FLV files. (There's also a
>   GUI frontend FLVMDIGUI). FLVMDI
>   optionally saves an XML version of the
>   injected data, and can add an
>   additional string data or save the
>   onMetaData data to an XML file. FLVMDI
>   has some unique functionality, but
>   it's not as vital now because flashcom
>   1.5.2+ and Flash Video Exporter 1.2+ adds the required metadata.
>   (Unfortunately there's still a gotcha
>   with Sorenson Squeeze 4, also see
>   Sorenson Squeeze (4.1) FLV Metadata
>   upate...).

A list of meta data it can inject can be found at the above link.